# Tensorflow starts fast and slows down during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

Im an electrical engineering student and im trying to model an industrial plant based on the power in a resistor inside a boiller, the temperature of the water in the boiller and the water flow passing through the boiller using python 3.5 and tensorflow.
The matter is that im a beginner at python and tensorflow and i wrote this code that works, but the trainning starts fast and rapidly start to slow down, and by the middle of the trainning its starts to taking ages between steps.
I just need some help on the optimization, and of course, any tips are welcome! 
Thank you very much!
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
input_vec_size = 3
step_size = 0.05
batch_size = 3
test_size = 16
train_end = 1905
eval_end = 290
predict_end = 1396
n_cores = 4
def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):
    line_reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    _, csv_row = line_reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
    time, power_in, temperature, flow = \
        tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    features = tf.pack([
        power_in,
        temperature
        ])
    return features, flow
def input_pipeline(directory, batch_size, n_cores, buffer_size, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
      tf.train.match_filenames_once(directory),
      shuffle=True)
    features, flow = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)
    x, y = tf.train.batch(
         [features, flow], batch_size=batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.001))
def init_bias(shape): #inicializa bias
    initial = tf.constant(0.001, shape=shape) #variancia 0.1
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def model(X, w_h, w_h2, w_o, B, B2, B3, p_keep_input, p_keep_hidden): 
    X = tf.nn.dropout(X, p_keep_input)
    h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, w_h)+B)
    h = tf.nn.dropout(h, p_keep_hidden)
    h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, w_h2)+B2)
    h2 = tf.nn.dropout(h2, p_keep_hidden)
    return tf.matmul(h2, w_o)+B3

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, input_vec_size])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float")
p_keep_input = tf.placeholder("float")
w_h = init_weights([input_vec_size, fclayer_size])
w_h2= init_weights([fclayer_size, fclayer_size])
w_o= init_weights([fclayer_size, 1])
B = init_bias([fclayer_size])
B2 = init_bias([fclayer_size])
B3 = init_bias([1])
py_x = model(X, w_h, w_h2, w_o, B, B2, B3, p_keep_input, p_keep_hidden)
predict_op = py_x[0]
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predict_op - Y))
train_op = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(step_size, 0.5).minimize(cost)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
directory = "./train/*.csv"
x, y = input_pipeline(directory, batch_size, n_cores, buffer_size, num_epochs=None)
directory_eval = "./eval/*.csv"
xe, ye = input_pipeline(directory_eval, test_size, n_cores, buffer_size, num_epochs=None)
directory_predict = "./predict/*.csv"
xp, yp = input_pipeline(directory_predict, test_size, n_cores, buffer_size, num_epochs=None)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    print("==================================TREINAMENTO=================================")
    for iteraction in range(int(train_end/batch_size)):
        trX, trY = sess.run([x,y])
        for i in range(0, batch_size):
            features, features_past, features_past2 = sess.run(tf.unpack(trX[i])), sess.run(tf.unpack(trX[i-1])), sess.run(tf.unpack(trX[i-2]))
        power_in_i = features[0] - 4
        temperature_i = features[1]
        temperature_i1 = features_past[1]
        temperature_i2 = features_past2[1]
        trX_now = tf.pack([power_in_i, (temperature_i-temperature_i1), (temperature_i-temperature_i2)])
        trX_now = sess.run(trX_now)
        X_Batch, Y_Batch = trX_now.reshape([-1, input_vec_size]), trY[i].reshape([-1, 1])
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: X_Batch,
                                      Y: Y_Batch, p_keep_input: 0.95, p_keep_hidden: 0.7})
        if(i%batch_size == 0):
            predict_train = sess.run(tf.reshape(predict_op, [-1, 1]), feed_dict={X: X_Batch, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
            train_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={py_x: predict_train, Y: Y_Batch})
            print("Train Batch:", iteraction,"Sample:", batch_size*iteraction, "X:", X_Batch, "Y:", Y_Batch, "y_:",
                predict_train, "Cost:", train_cost)
    saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print('Variaveis salvas com sucesso')
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
    print('=============================Fim do Treinamento=============================')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print("==============================VALIDAÇAO==================================")
    saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
    for iteraction in range(int(eval_end/test_size)):
        teX, teY = sess.run([xe, ye])
        for i in range(0, test_size):
            features, features_past, features_past2 = sess.run(tf.unpack(teX[i])), sess.run(tf.unpack(teX[i - 1])), sess.run(tf.unpack(teX[i-2]))
        power_in_i = features[0] - 4
        temperature_i = features[1]
        temperature_i1 = features_past[1]
        teX_now = tf.pack([power_in_i, (temperature_i - temperature_i1), (temperature_i-temperature_i2)])
        teX_now = sess.run(teX_now)
        X_Batch, Y_Batch = teX_now.reshape([-1, input_vec_size]), teY[i].reshape([-1, 1])
        predict_eval = sess.run(tf.reshape(predict_op, [-1, 1]), feed_dict={X: X_Batch, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
        eval_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={py_x: predict_eval, Y: Y_Batch})
        print("Eval Batch:", iteraction,"Sample:", batch_size*iteraction, "X:", X.eval(feed_dict={X: X_Batch}), "Y:", Y_Batch, "y_:",
             predict_eval, "Cost:", eval_cost)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
print('=============================FIM DA VALIDAÇAO=============================')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print("==============================PREDIÇÃO==================================")
    saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
    predict_batch_mean = 0
    predict_mean = 0
    for iteraction in range(int(predict_end / test_size)):
        tpX, tpY = sess.run([xp, yp])
        for i in range(0, test_size):
            features, features_past, features_past2 = sess.run(tf.unpack(tpX[i])), sess.run(tf.unpack(tpX[i - 1])), sess.run(tf.unpack(tpX[i-2]))
            power_in_i = features[0]- 4
            temperature_i = features[1]
            temperature_i1 = features_past[1]
            tpX_now = tf.pack([power_in_i, (temperature_i - temperature_i1), (temperature_i-temperature_i2)])
            tpX_now = sess.run(tpX_now)
            X_Batch, Y_Batch = tpX_now.reshape([-1, input_vec_size]), tpY[i].reshape([-1, 1])
            prediction = sess.run(tf.reshape(predict_op, [-1, 1]), feed_dict={X: X_Batch, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
            print("Predict Batch:", iteraction,"Sample:", batch_size*iteraction, "X:", X.eval(feed_dict={X: X_Batch}), "y_:",
                prediction)
            predict_batch_mean = (predict_batch_mean + prediction)/i
        predict_mean = (predict_mean + predict_batch_mean)/iteraction
        print("Predicted Flow:", predict_mean)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

My quick guess is that you are creating a lot of new nodes in each iteration through your training: those tf.packs and tf.reshapes are just making your graph bigger and bigger.

Construct the graph once outside the training loop, and I'll bet everything gets happy.

Comment: Im doing this because my features file contain temperature values, but for that problem i tought that the temperature diferences are better suited, so i got to unpack the present and the past features in order to get their values and subtract then to get the temp diference.
Is there a way to do this outside the for loop?
I tought that way because my decode_csv function reads line by line from the file, and i have to execute that function in order to get the features, present and past.

Comment: Sure, there are a number of things you can do: 1. read the csv and just use numpy to preprocess it into differenced input, 2. keep you reader code, call sess.run() once to get the differenced input values, 3. express the differencing in pure tensorflow calls. However you choose to do it, you want only one call to sess.run() in your training loop. You can probably save time if you try to build a toy example where you pass a numpy array to a placeholder, and have sess.run() return the data you actually want to train on - that should be easy to debug.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, friend!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas saved me this time, and im already in love with it!
After some learning, there is the working code. Now its fast, aside of the "not that good" prediction accuracy yet.
Heres the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

#VARIAVEIS
input_vec_size = 6
layer1_size = 512
fclayer_size = 1024
step_size = 0.02
test_size = 16
train_end = 1905
eval_end = 290
predict_end = 1396

#READS TRAIN FILE
def read_data(directory):
    data=pd.read_csv(directory, sep=',',header=None)
    return data

#Batch Maker
def get_batch(data, i, data_size):
    j = i + (input_vec_size - 1 - data_size)*(i//(data_size -     input_vec_size + 1)) + input_vec_size - 1
#    print(j, i//(data_size - 5))

    features = [(data[1][j] - 4)  / 16,
                (data[2][j] - data[2][j - 1])*10,
                (data[2][j] - data[2][j - 2])*10,
                (data[2][j] - data[2][j - 3])*10,
                (data[2][j] - data[2][j - 4])*10,
                (data[2][j] - data[2][j - 5])*10]
    features = np.reshape(features, [-1, input_vec_size])
    flow = data[3][j]/1500
    flow = np.reshape(flow, [-1,1])
    return features, flow

#Inicializaçao de variaveis
def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.001))

def init_bias(shape): #inicializa bias
  initial = tf.constant(0.001, shape=shape) #variancia 0.1
  return tf.Variable(initial)

#Definindo Modelo DNN
def model(X, w_h, w_h2, w_o, B, B2, p_keep_input, p_keep_hidden):
    X = tf.nn.dropout(X, p_keep_input)
    h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, w_h)+B)
    h = tf.nn.dropout(h, p_keep_hidden)
    h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, w_h2))
    h2 = tf.nn.dropout(h2, p_keep_hidden)
    return tf.matmul(h2, w_o)

#PLaceholders
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, input_vec_size])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float")
p_keep_input = tf.placeholder("float")

#Estados iniciais das variaveis
w_h = init_weights([input_vec_size, layer1_size])
w_h2= init_weights([layer1_size, fclayer_size])
w_o= init_weights([fclayer_size, 1])
B = init_bias([layer1_size])
B2 = init_bias([fclayer_size])
#Modelo
py_x = model(X, w_h, w_h2, w_o, B, B2, p_keep_input, p_keep_hidden)
#Operaçao de previsão
predict_op = tf.reshape(py_x[0], [-1,1])
#Funçao custo
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predict_op - Y))
#Operação de treinamento
train_op = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(step_size).minimize(cost)
#Utilizado para salvar as variaveis apos o treinamento
saver = tf.train.Saver()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    directory = '~/PycharmProjects/modelagemELT430/train/G2.csv'
    data = read_data(directory)
    for i in range(0, 10*(train_end - input_vec_size + 1)):
        features, flow = get_batch(data, i, train_end)
#        features = sess.run(features)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: features,
                          Y: flow, p_keep_input: 0.9, p_keep_hidden: 0.6})
        predict_train = sess.run(predict_op,
                             feed_dict={X: features, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
        train_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={py_x: predict_train, Y: flow})
        print("Train Sample:", i, "X:", features, "Y:", flow*1500, "y_:",
            predict_train*1500, "Cost:", train_cost)
    saver.save(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print('Variaveis salvas com sucesso')
    sess.close()
print('=============================Fim do Treinamento=============================')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    directory = '~/PycharmProjects/modelagemELT430/eval/G2E.csv'
    data = read_data(directory)
        print("==============================VALIDAÇAO==================================")
    saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
    for i in range(0, eval_end - input_vec_size + 1):
        features, flow = get_batch(data, i, eval_end)
        predict_eval = sess.run(predict_op,
                             feed_dict={X: features, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
        eval_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={py_x: predict_eval, Y: flow})
        print("Eval Sample:", i, "X:", features, "Y:",flow*1500, "y_:",predict_eval*1500, "Cost:", eval_cost)
    sess.close()
print('============================Fim da Validação=================================')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    directory = '~/PycharmProjects/modelagemELT430/predict/G2P.csv'
    data = read_data(directory)
    print("==============================Predição==================================")
    saver.restore(sess, "./model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")
    for i in range(0, predict_end - input_vec_size + 1):
        features, flow = get_batch(data, i, predict_end)
        predict = sess.run(predict_op,
                             feed_dict={X: features, p_keep_input: 1.0, p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
        eval_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={py_x: predict, Y: flow})
        print("Predict Sample:", i, "X:", features, "y_:",predict*1500)
    sess.close()
print('============================Fim da Prediçao=================================')
```

Comment: yes - your get_batch is still creating more nodes on each call. You need to call it once, then pass the read_data input to its returned value as a placeholder.

Comment: You ment the read_data output, right?
Or else i just didnt understand what u said, sorry, im really getting started at this. =0

Comment: yes, the output of read_data. sorry

Comment: I think, because the transport delay on this plant is so big, the FFNN cant model it properly. If anyone have some tip about how to get a better performance on the predictions in this model, i ll be veeeeeery thankfull!